# GC_FOR_ALLOCs ruin my simple search process

Tags: android, search, garbage-collection

Android Question:I want to search a String in a file instead of a database. Because my data needs to be encrypted. However it is very very slow, when I simply use a for or do-while to read a byte array, parse it to a class, compare the String using a method in the class. The code is like:

```
for (long p=0;positions[POS_WLIST]+p<positions[POS_BINDEX];) {
    byte[] frame = this.getFrame(positions[POS_WLIST] + p); //getFrame(long position) is to read a long (length) and then read a byte[length] from a RandomAccessFile at position
    Wort w = this.getWort(frame); //Wort is a message with protobuf, this method is a parseFrom(byte[]) method
    String str=w.getW().toLowerCase();
    if (str.length()>text.length()) {
        if (str.contains(text)) {
            //curOut.write(long2Byte(p));
            n++;
        }
    }
    p += frame.length + 3;
}
```

this loop runs about 130000 times and costs 20 seconds, and i get tons of GC_FOR_ALLOC(too many).

```
dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1373K, 27% free 18573K/25392K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1373K, 27% free 18573K/25392K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
....
```

if it is not obvious to find the problem,see this:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(testFile);
byte[] lengthByte=new byte[4];
byte[] content=null;
int lengthInt=0;
for (int i=0;i<150000;i++) {
    fis.read(lengthByte);
    lengthInt=byte2Int(lengthByte);

    content=new byte[lengthInt]; //10 bytes ~ 500 bytes at one time
    fis.read(content);

    //do something with content
}
```

even there's nothing to do with content, huge mount of GC_FOR_ALLOCs are displayed in logcat.

How can i achieve this simple search algorithm? I don't think i can avoid to write any new statements. With ObjectInputStream or BufferedReader the total time is still not decreased. Did anyone face with this GC_FOR_ALLOC problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: `String str=w.getW().toLowerCase();`  Please Google for, and understand, "java string immutable". You are also creating a new `Wort` everytime but you haven't shown us that so can't say what impact that has on memory allocation.

Comment: @Simon i think my code is not good as a sample, i have added more code to clear the problem. I think i need to create a new Wort or some other class to read a single object from the file so that i can compare it with a string. I have even saved my data as txt file and used the "readline", but it become much more slower when i run a decryption to each string.